# Android Flurry Integration with admob ads

Tags: android, admob, ads, flurry

I am integraing admob with flurry. I am receiving test ads from flurry. I add goggle services  and added following activities

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.flurry.admob.MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
        android:value="@string/appSpot_admob_apikey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.flurry.admob.test"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.flurry.admob.MYTEST_AD_DEVICE_ID"
        android:value="@string/appSpot_admob_testdevicekey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.flurry.admob.test"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.flurry.example.ad.mediated.all.BannerAdsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.flurry.example.ad.mediated.all.InterstitialAdsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
</application>
```

Here is my catlog errors

```
     07-16 14:52:57.437: E/FlurryAgent(9247): AdMob: package="com.flight.flight_app2": AndroidManifest.xml should include meta-data node with android:name="com.flurry.gms.ads.MY_AD_UNIT_ID" and not empty value for android:value

     07-16 14:52:57.437: E/FlurryAgent(9247): Cannot create ad network view for type: AdMob

     07-16 14:52:57.437: W/FlurryAgent(9247): Failed to create view for ad network: AdMob, network is unsupported on Android, or no ICustomAdNetworkHandler was registered or it failed to return a view.

     07-16 14:53:03.804: I/ViewRootImpl(9247): ViewRoot's MotionEvent : Down
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this : http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code/Android

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error message says:

```
AndroidManifest.xml should include meta-data node with android:name="com.flurry.gms.ads.MY_AD_UNIT_ID" and not empty value for android:value
```

So I would start by adding that.